# Our website is flagged as Suspicious Content by Vodafone and antimalware systems

Tags: malware, access-control, google-cloud

We've faced issue caused by marking our website as suspicious by Forcepoint and CleanMX. It caused us another problem. Vodafone has stopped letting users to our site.

Before, we had problems with that domain, letters from that domain came to spam folder.

This issue is appearing only on that domain. On our staging domain with the same content virustotal shows that there's no problems

Virustotal results: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/5f9ff8d4aa94bd6056f350581b3b322b7f5982aad5eef3084f14e752331c70b2/detection

What are Forcepoint's and CleanMX's criterias to flag sites as suspicious and how to get rid of that flag?